# Qt multithreading: How to append few QRunnable tasks to QThreadPool

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, threadpool

I am confused about how `QThreadPool` works, and can not find answer to it. I would like to have something like this:

```
class Task : public QRunnable { solve problem #nb }
```

Now, for example, I need to do 10 tasks which are not related and they does not share some values. I hope that I could do something like this:

```
QThreadPool pool;
pool.addTask(task1);
pool.addTask(task2);
pool.addTask(taskN);
pool.start();
```

For me, above example is a pool. I have few tasks, and I added to the pool and finally execute it all in each thread, but this is not how `QThreadPools` works. So, can I solve my problem using `QThreadPool`, or should I use something else?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically it works for your example like this (Note: I create the pool itself on the heap or it will be deleted at the end of the function scope)

```
pool = new QThreadPool(this);
pool->setMaxThreadCount (1);
pool->start(myQRunnablePtr1); 
pool->start(myQRunnablePtr2);
pool->start(myQRunnablePtr3);
// ...
pool->start(myQRunnablePtrN);
```

You could set the maxThreadCount higher if threads are allowed to run at the same time. In this example they will be executed in order of starting/queueing and the first has to end before the second will be run.

Additional you can add a priority to the start function, it you want to change the queueing later on. Lets say if you have a task that has to be started immediately.

The Class has some other use cases too (like tryStart) but this here might be enought for most cases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but why I would use thread anyway if I should wait first thread to finish to start second one. Or , you maybe want to say that if put `setMaxThreadCount(3)` that will execute first three runnables, and after finish it will execute second three?

Comment: Yes there is more than one way to use thie QThreadPool. If you want to have one Runnable executed after the other, set maxThreadCount to one. If it is ok that more than one runs at a time set it higher. But it does not wait for all the first three to finish in your example. As soon as one of them is done, the next one in the queue will be started, with allways having 3 running at the same time, until the queue is empty.

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyRunnable : public QObject, public QRunnable
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    explicit MyRunnable( int socket);
    virtual ~MyRunnable();
    virtual void run();

private:
    int socket_;
};

QThreadPool pool;
pool.setMaxThreadCount( 50 );
pool.start( new MyRunnable( socket), -1 );
```

Comment: Thanks. I find similar in documentation, but I want to know if I can put something like: `QVector<MyRunnable*> runnables` and then execute it like this `for(run : runnables) pool->start(run);` and expect that it will execute first e.g. 5 tasks in 5 threads?

Comment: why do you need a pool than since you want to execute each thread by hand?

Comment: Hm. No, I really do not want to handle threads myself. I just want to have something like queue which will handle threads. If queue has 100 tasks, and I have 8 threads on PC, I want to take 8 by 8 tasks to handle it. Second answer tells that this is possible with `QThreadPool`. Thanks!